# Unnecessary spaces in decimal display

Tags: verilog, space

I'm trying to display some 32-bit values in decimal format, and this is working fine other than the strange amount of unnecessary spaces between my `%d` and the previous character.

For example, if I have a 32-bit `reg` a with a decimal value of 33, I'll use something like this:

```
initial
begin
    $display("a=%d;", a);
end
```

The output in cmd would look similar to this:

```
a= ___________________33;
```

The line just represents the long blank space between `%d` and the previous character.
Can somebody explain to me why this happens and how can I get rid of the spaces?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) (21.2.1.3) you can find following information:

> When displaying decimal values, **leading zeros are suppressed and replaced by spaces**. In other radices, leading zeros are always displayed.

That's why you got so many spaces before `33`. The simplest way to achieve whay you want would be:

```
$display("a=%0d;", a);
```

By adding `0` between `%` character and `d` (letter that indicates the radix) the automatic sizing of displayed data is overridden. The result will be printed with minimum possible size.

Comment: Please use and quote the freely available [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf)